# Nginx Access-Log Request-Query-Parameters Password anonymisation

Tags: http, security, nginx

How to anonymize passwords in the accesslog of nginx?
I've a query-string like 'www.domain.tld?user=abc&password=123456&login=true' or a serialized json-object with a passwort as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

First add this to the server-section:

```
set $tempreq $request;
if ($tempreq ~ (.*passwor[dt]=)[^&]*(.*)) {
     set $tempreq $1******$2;
}
if ($tempreq ~ (.*passwor[dt]%22%3A%22).*?(%22.*)) {
     set $tempreq $1******$2;
}
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log passfilter;
```

Than add this to your http-section in the nginx.conf

```
log_format passfilter   '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '                                                                                             
                        '"$tempreq" $status $body_bytes_sent'                                                                                                    
                        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

It will mask passwords to ****** in query-strings like 'password=12345' and 'password%22%3A%22abcdef%22%2C'

Don't for get to check the config with 'sudo nginx -t' before reloading nginx.